# File Uploading by cordova android

Tags: cordova

How to upload an image to server by using cordova in android. with decrease the image size like 5MB file in around 100KB.
I am using:

```
function takefrontvc(value) {
            var clickvalue = "<input type='hidden' name='imagevalue' id='imagevalue' value='"+value+"'>";
            $("#clickvalue").html(clickvalue);
            // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) { },{
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
            });
        }
        function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {            
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";         
            //options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+'.png';
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

            options.mimeType="text/plain";
            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";
            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            var getvalue = $("#imagevalue").val(); 
            if(getvalue == "vcf") { $("#fvcloading").show(); }              
            if(getvalue == "vcb") { $("#bvcloading").show(); }      
            if(getvalue == "p1") {  $("#p1loading").show(); }
            if(getvalue == "p2") {  $("#p2loading").show(); }
            if(getvalue == "p3") {  $("#p3loading").show(); }
            if(getvalue == "p4") {  $("#p4loading").show(); }
            var uploadUrl = globalurl+"index.php/user/addfcp";
            ft.upload(imageURI, uploadUrl, win, fail, options);
        }
```